# Getting Null pointer exception on Autowire in spring boot - Alexa Integration

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build a Spring Boot Webservice for simple Hello world Alexa Skill.

I am getting Null pointer exception in run time on passing `vocabBrawlSpeechlet` aws speechlet API. Even if I pass `vocabBrawlSpeechlet` as `new VocabBrawlSpeechlet()` I am getting null pointer exception on using autowire inside vocabBrawlSpeechlet class.

Servlet class

```
package com.vocabBrawlAlexa;

@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends SpeechletServlet {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(HelloWorldServlet.class.getName());

  /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8294485619021129263L;


    private VocabBrawlSpeechlet vocabBrawlSpeechlet;

    @Autowired
    public HelloWorldServlet(VocabBrawlSpeechlet vocabBrawlSpeechlet) {
        LOGGER.debug("Autowiring vocabBrawlSpeechlet");
        this.vocabBrawlSpeechlet = vocabBrawlSpeechlet;
    }


public HelloWorldServlet() {
    LOGGER.debug(vocabBrawlSpeechlet);
    this.setSpeechlet(vocabBrawlSpeechlet);
  }
}
```

Speechlet class

```
package com.vocabBrawlAlexa.controller;  

@Component
public class VocabBrawlSpeechlet  implements SpeechletV2 {




    static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(VocabBrawlSpeechlet.class);


     private IAlexaService alexaService;

        /**
         * Constructor.
         *
         * @param alexaService service.
         */
        @Autowired
        public VocabBrawlSpeechlet(IAlexaService alexaService) {
            this.alexaService = alexaService;
        }

    public VocabBrawlSpeechlet() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    @Override
    public void onSessionStarted(SpeechletRequestEnvelope<SessionStartedRequest> requestEnvelope) {
        log.info("onSessionStarted " );
        log.info("Request requestId "+requestEnvelope.getRequest().getRequestId()
                +" session Id "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getSessionId()+
                " user ID "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getUser().getUserId());        
        // any initialization logic goes here
    }

    @Override
    public SpeechletResponse onLaunch(SpeechletRequestEnvelope<LaunchRequest> requestEnvelope) {
        log.info("onLaunch");
        log.info("Request requestId "+requestEnvelope.getRequest().getRequestId()
                +" session Id "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getSessionId()+
                " user ID "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getUser().getUserId());
        return getWelcomeResponse();
    }

    @Override
    public SpeechletResponse onIntent(SpeechletRequestEnvelope<IntentRequest> requestEnvelope) {
        IntentRequest request = requestEnvelope.getRequest();
        log.debug("reached Intent");
        log.info("onIntent");
        log.info("Request requestId "+requestEnvelope.getRequest().getRequestId()
                +" session Id "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getSessionId()+
                " user ID "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getUser().getUserId());

        Intent intent = request.getIntent();
        String intentName = (intent != null) ? intent.getName() : null;

        if ("HelloWorldIntent".equals(intentName)) {
            log.debug("HelloWorldIntent Intent");
            log.debug(alexaService);
            //IAlexaService alexa = new AlexaServiceImpl();
            return alexaService.getHelloIntentResponse();
        } else if ("AMAZON.HelpIntent".equals(intentName)) {
            return getHelpResponse();
        } else {
            return getAskResponse("HelloWorld", "This is unsupported.  Please try something else.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionEnded(SpeechletRequestEnvelope<SessionEndedRequest> requestEnvelope) {
        log.info("onSessionEnded");
        log.info("Request requestId "+requestEnvelope.getRequest().getRequestId()
                +" session Id "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getSessionId()+
                " user ID "+requestEnvelope.getSession().getUser().getUserId());
        // any cleanup logic goes here
    }

    /**
     * Creates and returns a {@code SpeechletResponse} with a welcome message.
     *
     * @return SpeechletResponse spoken and visual response for the given intent
     */
    private SpeechletResponse getWelcomeResponse() {
        String speechText = "Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit, you can say hello";
        return getAskResponse("HelloWorld", speechText);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a {@code SpeechletResponse} for the hello intent.
     *
     * @return SpeechletResponse spoken and visual response for the given intent
     */
    private SpeechletResponse getHelloResponse() {
        log.debug("reached hello world");
        String speechText = "Hello world";

        // Create the Simple card content.
        SimpleCard card = getSimpleCard("HelloWorld", speechText);

        // Create the plain text output.
        PlainTextOutputSpeech speech = getPlainTextOutputSpeech(speechText);

        return SpeechletResponse.newTellResponse(speech, card);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a {@code SpeechletResponse} for the help intent.
     *
     * @return SpeechletResponse spoken and visual response for the given intent
     */
    private SpeechletResponse getHelpResponse() {
        String speechText = "You can say hello to me!";
        return getAskResponse("HelloWorld", speechText);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method that creates a card object.
     * @param title title of the card
     * @param content body of the card
     * @return SimpleCard the display card to be sent along with the voice response.
     */
    private SimpleCard getSimpleCard(String title, String content) {
        SimpleCard card = new SimpleCard();
        card.setTitle(title);
        card.setContent(content);

        return card;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method for retrieving an OutputSpeech object when given a string of TTS.
     * @param speechText the text that should be spoken out to the user.
     * @return an instance of SpeechOutput.
     */
    private PlainTextOutputSpeech getPlainTextOutputSpeech(String speechText) {
        PlainTextOutputSpeech speech = new PlainTextOutputSpeech();
        speech.setText(speechText);

        return speech;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method that returns a reprompt object. This is used in Ask responses where you want
     * the user to be able to respond to your speech.
     * @param outputSpeech The OutputSpeech object that will be said once and repeated if necessary.
     * @return Reprompt instance.
     */
    private Reprompt getReprompt(OutputSpeech outputSpeech) {
        Reprompt reprompt = new Reprompt();
        reprompt.setOutputSpeech(outputSpeech);

        return reprompt;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method for retrieving an Ask response with a simple card and reprompt included.
     * @param cardTitle Title of the card that you want displayed.
     * @param speechText speech text that will be spoken to the user.
     * @return the resulting card and speech text.
     */
    private SpeechletResponse getAskResponse(String cardTitle, String speechText) {
        SimpleCard card = getSimpleCard(cardTitle, speechText);
        PlainTextOutputSpeech speech = getPlainTextOutputSpeech(speechText);
        Reprompt reprompt = getReprompt(speech);

        return SpeechletResponse.newAskResponse(speech, reprompt, card);
    }
}
```

Application class

```
package com.vocabBrawlAlexa;

@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
@ComponentScan("com.vocabBrawlAlexa")
public class VocabBrawlAlexaApplication {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(VocabBrawlAlexaApplication.class.getName());



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.info("Info Message Logged !!!");
         //setAmazonProperties();


        LOGGER.info("Info Message Logged asdfsa !!!");
        setAmazonProperties();

        SpringApplication.run(VocabBrawlAlexaApplication.class, args);

    }

    /**
     * Sets system properties which are picked up by the {@link SpeechletServlet}.
     */
    private static void setAmazonProperties() {
        // Disable signature checks for development
        LOGGER.info("Info Message Logged setAmazonProperties !!!");
        System.setProperty(Sdk.DISABLE_REQUEST_SIGNATURE_CHECK_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");
        // Allow all application ids for development
        System.setProperty(Sdk.SUPPORTED_APPLICATION_IDS_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "amzn1.ask.skill.1672b699-610a-42b6-83cb-0a4e7c9f5ccf");
        // Disable timestamp verification for development
        System.setProperty(Sdk.TIMESTAMP_TOLERANCE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "1500");
    }    
}
```

**Update :**

I have removed the default constructor as per the suggestion. PFB the changed servlet code

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends SpeechletServlet {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(HelloWorldServlet.class.getName());

  /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8294485619021129263L;


    private VocabBrawlSpeechlet vocabBrawlSpeechlet;

    @Autowired
    public HelloWorldServlet(VocabBrawlSpeechlet vocabBrawlSpeechlet) {
        LOGGER.debug("Autowiring vocabBrawlSpeechlet");
        this.vocabBrawlSpeechlet = vocabBrawlSpeechlet;
        this.setSpeechlet(this.vocabBrawlSpeechlet);

    }

}
```

During the first hit, I got 500 exception after that I am getting 404

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.vocabBrawlAlexa.HelloWorldServlet
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:368)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Remove the default constructors and post the stack trace.

Comment: didn't get you. you want me to remove  @Autowired
        public VocabBrawlSpeechlet(IAlexaService alexaService) {
            this.alexaService = alexaService;
        } and inject it as this.setSpeechlet(new vocabBrawlSpeechlet()); right?

Comment: See what happens if you remove all other constructors except for the autowired one

Comment: No I want you to remove the default constructors... The no-args constructors.

Comment: where to put this.setSpeechlet(vocabBrawlSpeechlet); if I have to remove that HelloWorldServlet() constructor? Alexa will not work without this

Comment: Put it into the other constructor, the one that's autowired

Comment: Ok trying now.  will update the trace soon. thanks for the patience :)

Comment: @AndreasHartmann removed the construction as per suggestion. Now I am getting InstantiationException. :(

Comment: That seems like a different issue, check the documentation to see if you are using the @WebServlet annotation correctly.

Comment: But If I put this.setSpeechlet(new vocabBrawlSpeechlet()); servlet is working fine and it's going inside vocabBrawlSpeechlet class. Again alexaService autowire is coming as null :(